# Summernote content display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, summernote

I am using summernote editor for my application . The content getting saved how user has saved, ex- first content, image and then video. I want to display the content in same sequence as user has typed and saved. Please suggest something. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe if you show some code we can do better. Don't you think?

Comment: <p>sedasdsqef</p><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/FdKxwD_w7Es" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe><p><br></p><p>Summernote content</p> I am storing the editor content like this... I want to display it in a same format .. First plain text then video should come.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code. But not the html in the editor. The JS code for the editor!!! :) We can't help to fix your js code if we don't see what you have done so far!